# How to install and run JavaRE on Busybox?

Tags: java, installation, execution, busybox

I have installed Busybox on an virtual machine created with linux containers(lxc) and now I have to install javaRE to run my java application on it.

I have downloaded and installed into Busybox the RPM for linux x86 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) but when I try to start ./java from /usr/java/bin/  [that is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33AQg.png)

It seems like it can not see the executable or maybe I launch the wrong file, surely I am wrong somewhere but I do not understand where.

I have tried to find a solution but I do not find someone that have the same problem.

Thank you!